# how to require a document for a test case and not have it run?

Tags: ruby, testcase

I've created a terminal game, and I'm now suppose to write test cases for it. I've researched how to write test cases, and have the general idea of how you are suppose to crete them and what they do, however I'm having an issue, in requiring the terminal game in the test case, and instead of running the test case it runs the game, I'm not sure how to fix this and therefore don;t know how to continue with my game. Please help, thanks.

```
require 'test/unit'
require_relative '/Users/Vanessaperez/SchoolInvasion/skeleton/lib/schoolinvasion.rb'

class TestSchoolInvasion < Test::Unit::TestCase


def test_room()
assert_equal(main_lobby, """This room is the center with the option to go straight, into the         hallway or to the outside.""")
assert_equal(main_lobby.name, "MainLobby")
assert_equal(main_lobby.path, {})
end

def test_room_paths()
    center = Room.new("Center", "Test room in the center.")
    north = Room.new("North", "Test room in the north.")
    south = Room.new("South", "Test room in the south.")

    center.add_paths({:north => north, :south=> south})
    assert_equal(center.go(:north), north)
    assert_equal(center.go(:south), south)
    end

def test_map()
assert_equal("Start", "You can go left, right and straight.")
assert_equal("Right", "There are a pair of doublt doors at the end, you can go outside or return   to the main lobby.")
assert_equal("Straight", "You enter a hallway with a lab, cafeteria, english class, janitors     closet and a biology class.")
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need for `schoolinvasion.rb` to run the game when executed from the command line, and yet not run the game when it is required by the test.  To do that, `schoolinvasion.rb` should compare `__FILE__` to `$0`, like so:

```
run_my_game if $0 == __FILE__
```

Where `run_my_game` is, for example, a call to your game's main method.

This works because `$0` is set to the path of the ruby file that was first executed.  If $0 is equal to the path of `schoolivasion.rb`, then it's game time.  If it's not (say, the test is what you ran), then it's not game time.

Comment: So $0 == /Users/Vanessaperez/SchoolInvasion/skeleton/lib/schoolinvasion.rb and this is saying that only if this specific path is executed then the game should run? Oh, and now it says unknown regexp options - klt (SyntaxError)... what does that mean, @Wayne Conrad

Comment: @Nessa545 Try it.  No matter what path you give to execute the script, it will work.

Comment: I did, it says "schoolinvasion.rb:4: unknown regexp options - kit" I typed it as     run_my_game()
     if $0 == ~/schoolinvasion/skeleton/lib/SchoolInvasion.rb
    end # run_my_game and as    def run_my_game()
         if $0 == ~/schoolinvasion/skeleton/lib/SchoolInvasion.rb
        end # run_my_game neither worked, what am I doing wrong? @Wayne Conrad

Comment: @Nessa545 Ah, I see what went wrong.  Don't type in an actual path.  Type in `__FILE__`, just as it appears above.

Comment: oh okay, I did it, but now it says "undefined method `run_my_game' for main:Object (NoMethodError)" .... any idea why? @Wayne Conrad, and if I haven't said it, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Nessa545 Replace `run_my_game` with a call to your program's main method.  And you're welcome!